# Where is slf4j coming from and how to make it to use log4j-core 2.17.1

Tags: maven, log4j, slf4j

We have a maven project on scala, where it implicitly using slf4j with log4j of version 1.2.17. Must upgrade it to log4j 2.17.1. In my pom file there is no slf4j dependency and it is somehow still using it. [image]

Is there any command to scan the dependency tree to find which dependency is using slf4j? And how can I make it to use log4j-core 2.17.1?
[image]

```html
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ml.dmlc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xgboost4j-spark</artifactId>
            <version>0.81</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.typesafe</groupId>
            <artifactId>config</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scalamock</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalamock-scalatest-support_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-scala_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.holdenkarau</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-testing-base_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}_0.11.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazon.deequ</groupId>
            <artifactId>deequ</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-rc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqs</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.9</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting the `slf4j-api` as a transitive dependency from one of your other logging related dependencies. However there is no `slf4j` bindings in your class path as well which is good. If I answer for your question how you can use `slf4j-api`, it is purely used as an logging facade. Use `slf4j` for logging in your application and don't user `log4j` loggers. In long run it will be beneficial because even if you want to change the logging mechanism you'll not require any code changes. `slf4j` can be used via `@Slf4j` or via a logger instance as well. If you use `@Slf4j`, then you'll have to add `lombok` to your class path.

Example for logger instance based logging:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
    
    public void testLog() {
        logger.info("Test");
    }
```

Example for `@Slf4j` annotation based logging:

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class LoggingTest {

    public void testLog() {
        log.info("Test");
    }

}
```

For further reading please refer [slf4j](https://www.slf4j.org/) documentations.

Comment: Is there any way to make it use log4j-core 2.17.x?

Comment: Yes, you don't need to do anything explicitly for that. In your class path you have log4j and slf4j. Slf4j will internally recognize that you are using log4j for logging and it has slf4j-log4j bindings. You can use slf4j to log via log4j2 without doing any manual change.

Comment: Thanks. Added these three dependencies as mentioned here https://howtodoinjava.com/log4j2/log4j2-with-slf4j/. But still, it is using  log4j-extras version of 1.2.17

Comment: The dependency which is using slf4j is apache spark-core

Comment: log4j-extra is a jar file full of additional functionality for log4j. 1.2.17 is the latest available version of log4-extras. Don't conflict its version with the log4j2 core dependencies version which is 2.17.1. If you can add your POM file it will give a better idea about your dependencies.

Comment: I added dependencies used in project

Comment: Thanks! Now I can see your POM file and I see you are using log4j 1.2.17 which you are going to upgrade to 2.17.1. I answered for couple of your questions in the comments and would you please raise the real problem here. Because initially you wanted to know how to use slf4j with log4j and I guess its clear now. After that you had a confusion about log4j-extra version. If you can explain the concern more I would really appreciate, thanks!

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue. I am facing similar issue. I am also getting this log4j as transitive dependency from spark